# Wrap data image with deep link using Branch IO

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io, facebook-sdk-4.x

I want to use `Branch IO` on `Facebook`. I want to send an image to `Facebook`. I saw that in example on `Branch IO` website, looks like we need to sent image url instead of upload data image.

**My question is**, Are we able to send image to `Facebook` which will be wrapped with `deep link` without sending image to a server or to `S3 amazon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: uploading images is not possible using the iOS SDK. You'll need to host the image somewhere else (like S3) and use that URL for the link image.

It is possible to upload images when manually creating links on the Branch dashboard, but that cannot be done programmatically from within an app.