# Using Amazon AWS S3 for simple file sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, branch.io

I'm trying to integrate AWS s3 to my app for sharing images.

I'm currently using Branch.io for sharing content between devices using deep links. But this approach have a problem. I cannot send image data with deep links [as explained in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331884/wrap-data-image-with-deep-link-using-branch-io)

So, having the same post as reference, I tried to use AWS S3 for uploading files and then sharing the links. But I believe this approach requires my app to have a login function for Cognito but I do not want that.

I also tried generating presigned urls for the images but then, my credentials expire after an hour and I get an "Expired token" error. I'm currently using this approach, I just wish it wouldn't expire in an hour. 7 days or so is enough for me, but an hour is too short.

I can also make images uploaded for sharing public, therefore access it freely from anywhere but I don't like that either for security reasons.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by not using temporary credentials generated by AWS SDK. I instead, created a new user for the app through AWS dashboard, gave it the necessary permissions to be able to upload the objects. In the code, I generated a new basic AWS credential with the id and secret key of the new user.

Now I can create a presigned url and it works up to 1 week. I can even increase the expire date by using V2 signing.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate the URL you need to pass in the timeout parameter,

> var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey', **Expires: 604800**};

Sample code to generate getSigned URL.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'myKey', Expires: 604800};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
console.log("get URL is", url);
```

604800 seconds in a week.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm able to set expire date for the uri itself and I'm sure it's working fine. What doesn't work is the temp credentials. It creates a session for a few hours. When the session ends, the link becomes unusable.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use S3 Pre-signed URLs which has maximum expriation of 7 days. you can set it with query string parameter "X-Amz-Expires".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Like I said, with that approach, I get a token expired error after an hour on the link. After searching that issue, I found out the credentials provider expires the session and the link becomes unusable after that.

Answer (score 0):

Amruta from Branch here:

Unfortunately, there is no way to add images to the link using the Branch SDK. As a workaround, as mentioned in the post you have tagged, you can create links on the Branch dashboard and upload images in the Social media tab. Once, the link is saved the same tab will provide you with the link for the image hosted by Branch.

[image]

Unfortunately, this would only work if you have a predefined set of images.